# Will an E5-2660 be a major improvement over a Q9550 for a webserver?

Tags: linux, web-server, web-hosting, intel, benchmark

I have an old production server that runs Debian on a Q9550 CPU. I want to upgrade the server but I am on a very tight budget. I can't spend more than around $600. I can get a refurbished HP ProLiant DL380P G8 with 32GB RAM and 2x E5-2660 CPU for about that price.

Will the (dual) E5-2660 be a major improvement over the Q9550? If I look at both CPU's on cpubenchmark.net, the E5-2660 has a passmark score about 3x as high as the Q9550. But all other comparison sites say they are about the same speed.

Answer (score 2):

The E5-2660 will be a improvement in CPU performance over the Q9550. It's a 4 year old newer chip and has 8 cores vs 4, and since your new system is a dual CPU you will have 16 cores, 4 times as many as before. On top of that, you also have Hyper-Threading which the Q9550 does not have.

According to CPU Mark rating [found here](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-Core2-Quad-Q9550-vs-Intel-Xeon-E5-2660/1049vs1219):

Multi-threaded:

**Q9550:** 3,959

**E5-2660:** 11,279

Single-threaded:

**Q9550:** 1,196

**E5-2660:** 1,473

According to those numbers, you would at the very least see a 25% gain and could see nearly a 300% gain depending on your application's scaling.